# Is it possible to do .net code scraping

Tags: .net, regex, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I've got the following piece of code:

```
Lingua.Find(Me.ViewUtente.IDLingua).Descrizione

Valuta.Find(Me.ViewUtente.IDValuta).Descrizione
```

Both the methods are calling a (different) stored procedure like this way.

```
Public Function LoadFromID(ByVal IDLingua As Int16) As DataRow

            Dim parameters As SqlParameter() = { _
                GetSQLParameter("@switch", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 0), _
                GetSQLParameter("@IDLingua", SqlDbType.SmallInt, IDLingua)}

            Using ds As DataSet = RunProcedure("dbo.proc_Lingua", parameters, "Lingua_LoadFromID")
```

I would like to get the name of the called stored procedure. Of course for two methods would be enough to press F12, but imagine having 200 methods.. I would like to automatize this task.

Before a code migration there is a phase of analysis. And In the software I have to migrate there are no JOINS on DB it always retrieves the basic table which has got the FK of the others; then it goes again to the DB and looks on that table (*"Lingua"*, *Valuta* and so on).

I would like to auto write my new code.. And I can do it since the stucture of the old code is very structured.

Is there any way to do that? Using regex, or any other system? Or even also simply the name of this ambit of stuff.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Why do you need a regex to get two names of stored procedures you can just get from the code yourself? What do you need the regex for?

Comment: @mrhobo: Making it in an automatic way for all the code calls

Comment: still unclear. Make what automatic? How does regex fit in?

Comment: Am I correct that the code is VB.NET while you tagged this with c#?

Comment: @rene: you are rigth, corrected and +1 for the suggestion